# How do I uninstall android studio in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, uninstallation, ubuntu-20.04

I download Android Studio - Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 from their official website in my ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

My installation Process:

I downloaded the zip file and extracted it.
I cd into the /bin/ directory and executed the **studio.sh** file using ./studio.sh command.
The installation went through but now I'm having a lot of problems.

I want to completely uninstall it without altering anything but don't know how.
I would be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, try to delete all the hidden files of Android from the home directory if any exist.  Hidden files are in .cache/Google/ and .config/Google of your home directory.

Then, type the following commands in Terminal.

```
$ cd /usr/local

$ sudo rm -r ./android-studio
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the hidden files are in `.cache/Google/` and `.config/Google` of your home directory.

Answer (score 9):

```bash
sudo snap remove android-studio
```

Comment: OP didn't use `snap`, he "downloaded the zip"..."from their official website".

Answer (score 8):

studio.sh is not an installer. It is the starter.

Uninstall is to delete the directory where you extract the package, no other steps.

BTW, I run Android Studio Arctic Fox on my Linux Mint very well, what are your problems? Mint suppose to be same as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

When you download the .zip file and extract it, the `/android-studio/` folder then also has file `Install-Linux-tar.txt`, which says:

> By default, Android Studio stores all your settings in the
> ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1 directory
> and uses ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1 as a data cache.

That means you have to visit these directories and delete their content.

Don't forget to delete the `/android-studio/` folder too. You might have downloaded it either to `/usr/local/` for your user profile or `/opt/` for shared users. If so, to delete the `/android-studio/` folder, go to Terminal and type:

> sudo rm -r /usr/local/android-studio/

or

> sudo rm -r /opt/android-studio/

respectively.

Answer (score 3):

As you installed with zip file go into directory where you installed it then do `rm` file created there

**note** if you have added it to you path also you need to remove it by `rm -rf android-studio/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to delete all of the following directories:

```
rm -rf ~/Android
rm -rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects (only if you did not make any projects here)
rm -rf ~/.cache/Android\ Open\ Source\ Project
rm -rf ~/.cache/Google
rm -rf ~/.config/Android\ Open\ Source\ Project
rm -rf ~/.config/Google
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Android\ Open\ Source\ Project
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google
rm -rf ~/.local/share/android-studio (or any directory of your choice to install)
```

(edited) Further, to delete existing emulators

```
rm -rf ~/.android
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked :-

```
sudo apt-get remove android-studio
```