# Unable to start Android Studio Flamingo on my Linux laptop

Tags: android-studio, installation

I just installed Android Studio Flamingo [starting at this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/) (actually, an upgrade from Electric Eel) and when I opened it, I got the following funky screen:

[image]

I tried opening one of my projects by selecting the project name, but after the screen changes for a moment, it returns to the above. So my first question is, is this the screen I'm supposed to see after opening Flamingo? Second, why can't I open any of my Android projects?

Edit: After restarting Studio, I got the following errors:

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:/usr/local/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2023-05-04 10:07:22,114 [   2785] SEVERE - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Cannot init component state (componentName=ProjectId, componentClass=ProjectIdManager) [Plugin: com.intellij]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot init component state (componentName=ProjectId, componentClass=ProjectIdManager
.
.

Update: I made progress by following the suggestion [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories): the Welcome screen is bypassed when I ran the startup script studio.sh in the Android Studio bin directory. However, I still can't open any of my projects.

**UPDATE**: I did what CodeFoxy suggested and although I was able to open my projects, I got errors due to an old JDK used by the projects (JDK 11, but Flamingo needs JDK 17). So I changed the projects to use the embedded SDK, but when I restarted Flamingo, I got this error:

[image]

**UPDATE 3** One other piece of information: The reason why the Kotlin file wasn't found was because the libraries directory never got created:

```
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/android-studio$ cd .idea
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/android-studio/.idea$ cd 
libraries
bash: cd: libraries: No such file or directory
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/android-studio/.idea$ ls
misc.xml  workspace.xml
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/android-studio/.idea$
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was caused by the existence of .bak directories in ~/cache/Google. Apparently, when Android Studio starts up, it wants to read everything in that directory; I think this is a bug and told the support team that.

Anyway, once I moved them and fixed some permissions, Flamingo had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to completely uninstall android studio and removing all the hidden files related to android studio.

[How do I uninstall android studio in Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68902537/how-do-i-uninstall-android-studio-in-ubuntu-20-04)

you can refer to above link if you use ubuntu. for other distros the process should be the similar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

completely reinstall it will be better

First, try to delete all the hidden files of Android from the home directory if any exist. Hidden files are in .cache/Google/ and .config/Google of your home directory.

Then, type the following commands in Terminal.

`cd /usr/local`

`sudo rm -r ./android-studio`

and reinstall it

some info is from:[How do I uninstall android studio in Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68902537/how-do-i-uninstall-android-studio-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried what you suggested and what was suggested in the link and I still got the same result.

Comment: then you can try using a vm to install android studio release

Comment: heres a good tool: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads virtualbox